# Gray scale output using pdflatex

Tags: graphics, pdf, viewers, printing

I use colour diagrams (saved as pdf files) which I include in my LaTeX file. Is there any options in pdflatex to create a gray scale document or a pdf viewer where you can view the document in gray scale?

Enabling you to view the document and fix any problems before it gets printed on a non-colour printer.

Comment: I don't think it's useful since it does not show it the way the printer converts it internally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. None of the TeX engines (`pdftex`, `XeTeX`, `LuaTeX`) allows color correction of included images. The best you can do is set all colors *generated* in your document to gray scale.